# SSIS & SQL Server - Use SSIS Execute SQL Task to run a stored procedure in SQL Server then return the result set to SSIS object variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, ado.net

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server 2012:

```
USE [GESTAO_ATUARIAL]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [Atuaria].[CalcularFatorMensalizacaoTeste] @taxaJuros NUMERIC(7, 4) AS
    -- Variaveis
    DECLARE @woolhouse DECIMAL(16, 15) = 0.458333333333333;

    -- Fator de mensalização usa apenas tábua de mortalidade e taxa de juros
    ;WITH cte AS (
        -- Âncora
        SELECT
            Idade,
            CAST(Feminino AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS qxFeminino,
            CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS vx,
            CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS lxFeminino,
            CAST(Masculino AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS qxMasculino,
            CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS lxMasculino
        FROM Atuaria.RP2000SuavizadaMenos20 AS rp
        WHERE Idade = 0

        -- Parte recursiva
        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            cte.Idade + 1,
            CAST(Feminino AS NUMERIC(28, 25)),
            CAST((vx / (1 + @taxaJuros)) AS NUMERIC(28, 25)),
            CAST((lxFeminino * (1 - qxFeminino)) AS NUMERIC(28, 25)),
            CAST(Masculino AS NUMERIC(28, 25)),
            CAST((lxMasculino * (1 - qxMasculino)) AS NUMERIC(28, 25))
        FROM Atuaria.RP2000SuavizadaMenos20 AS rp
        JOIN cte
            ON cte.Idade + 1 = rp.Idade

        WHERE cte.Idade < 120
        
    ),
    -- Cálculo de Dx
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT
            cte.Idade,
            CAST(vx * lxFeminino AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS DxFeminino,
            CAST(vx * lxMasculino AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) AS DxMasculino
        FROM cte
    ) 
    -- Cálculo dos fatores de mensalização feminino e masculino
    SELECT
        Idade,
        CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) - @woolhouse / 
            (SUM(DxFeminino) OVER (ORDER BY Idade ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) / NULLIF(DxFeminino, 0)) AS FatorMensalizacaoFeminino,
        CAST(1.0 AS NUMERIC(28, 25)) - @woolhouse / 
            (SUM(DxMasculino) OVER (ORDER BY Idade ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) / NULLIF(DxMasculino, 0)) AS FatorMensalizacaoMasculino
    FROM cte2 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The procedure above uses a CTE to generate a table with 121 rows and three columns. It takes interest rate as the single parameter and it uses a mortality table to calculate some actuary variables.

I am using SSIS to run all the complex calculations, it works, but the way I am using this specific procedure creates a lot of tables in the database and I'd like to simplify that.

What I am doing currently is to copy the code of the CTE to create a procedure for each benefit plan (11 in total). It is the same code but in separate stored procedures.

Instead of passing the result to a SSIS object variable I am creating a table to store the results for each benefit plan:

```
;WITH cte AS (

) SELECT * FROM cte INTO MyBenefitPlan1
```

Therefore, I have 11 stored procedures doing the same thing, only generating different tables because each plan has a different interest rate.

After that, I use yet another Execute SQL Task to retrieve the table created by the CTE in the stored procedure and then I pass the result set to a SSIS object variable.

What I need to know is how to execute this stored procedure from a Execute SQL Task and pass its results directly to a SSIS object variable.

I am using ADO.NET as the connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the object variable(s) you need in the SSIS Variables window.
2. In the execute SQL task properties, in the "general" tab of the execute SQL task editor, change the result set property to "full result set".
3. Map the result set to the variable in the Result Set tab of the execute SQL task editor. "Add" a mapping, for result set put `0`, and select the appropriate object variable in the variable name dropdown.
4. *If you are using a script task to process the data:* Since you are using ADO.NET, the type of the result set will be a `System.Data.DataSet`. This is different from what you will get from OLEDB, so you don't `DataAdapter.Fill()` a data table from the SSIS object. Instead get the `.Value` of the SSIS variable, cast it directly to a `DataSet`, then use the `.Tables` property to get your `DataTable`.